# Como instalar lua no ubuntu via terminal?

Tags: lua

Ja tentei de tudo, escrevo apt-get install lua5.1 ou lua5.2, ele fala que é impossivel encontrar pacote

Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
E: Impossível encontrar o pacote lua5.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'lua5.1'
E: Não foi possível encontrar o pacote através da expressão regular 'lua5.1'

Ja tentei ver se eu já tinha uma versão, eu não tenho

Tentei baixar pelo site deles, não consegui também, se alguem tiver como me ajudar ai.

Comment: Veja http://www.lua.org/start.html#building

Answer (score 0):

Aparamente numa nova instalação o cache de pacotes não lista o lua.
Porém basta atualizar: `sudo apt-get update`.

Rodando Ubuntu através do Docker:

```bsh
docker run -it --rm ubuntu bash
```

Erro ao tentar instalar a lua:

```bsh
root@2d889582f79b:/# apt-get install lua5.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lua5.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'lua5.2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lua5.2'
```

Pacotes atualizados e o começo da instalação:

```
root@2d889582f79b:/# apt-get update > /dev/null
root@2d889582f79b:/# apt-get install lua5.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libreadline7 readline-common
Suggested packages:
  readline-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreadline7 lua5.2 readline-common
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 274 kB of archives.
After this operation, 853 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```